# Case on union of multiple unions and issue with alias

Tags: sql, union, case, alias

I have 2 series of unions which I wish to join by another union. In the first one, I have 3 `Selects` and in the second one I have 2 different `Selects`.

```
Select id, min(value)
from table1 t1
join (Select id, value
      Union
      Select id, value
      Union
      Select id, value) as foo 
  on foo.id=t1.id
  Group by id

Select id, max(value)
from table1 t1
join (Select id, value
      Union
      Select id, value) as bar 
  on bar.id=t1.id
  Group by id
```

I tried to do a union between these two, but it made things pretty complicated. My biggest issue is with my alias. My second is with the case linked to my value columns, which I wish to name value.

```
Select (alias).id, 
       Case 
           When foo.value= 0 or bar.value=1 THEN 1
           Else 0
       End as value
from table1 t1
Join (Select id, min(value)
      from table1 t1
      join (Select id, value
            Union
            Select id, value
            Union
            Select id, value) as foo
            on foo.id=t1.id
            Group by id
      UNION
      Select id, max(value)
      from table1 t1
      join (Select id, value
            Union
            Select id, value) as bar 
        on bar.id=t1.id
        Group by id) as (alias) 
  on ??.id=??.id
```

I wrote my case the way I think it should be written, but normally, when there are more than one column with the same name, SQL states it as ambiguous. I am still unsure if I should use `UNION` or `INTERSECT`, but I assume either of them would be done the same way. How should I deal with this?

Comment: There is a logical problem with your final query: your case condition `When foo.value= 0 or bar.value=1` - in the outer query, there is no way to tell which values came from which sub-query. Not only that, but `UNION` and `INTERSECT` do significantly different things - it isn't clear which one you want to do. Can you rephrase your question, either to explain *what* you are trying to do instead of *how* you are trying to do it, or alternatively to explain the *exact* problem you currently have?

Comment: Can you provide your tables layouts? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please describe what you want to do.  The queries in your `union`s have no `from` clauses.  You are using aggregation functions without a `group by`.  And it is entirely unclear what you are trying to join.

Comment: @MarkBannister My first union is looking for a max value and my second union is looking for a min, so I cannot use union of all 5, which is why I divided my unions. However, I wish to have all of the ids that have either a certain value is the #1 or a certain value in #2, hence the case. My first issue is with the alias at the end of `union` if I use is and my second issue is to have a case that works with both my union

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added the `group by` where they should be. I can add the from and join for every `Select`, but I think these lines are just trifle here since every select works individually and my foo and bar unions work individually too. My issue is with the union of foo and bar and the case I want do from my inner unions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this right, you probably want something like this

```
SELECT ...
FROM ( ... union #1 ) AS u1
JOIN (... union #2 ) AS u2 ON u1.id = u2.id
```